# How to use git rerere (or similar) for automatic resolution of "Submodule merge conflict"s?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-rerere

I'm trying to rebase a branch B over a branch A, but one of the newest commits in A deletes one folder replacing it with a git submodule.

After running `git rebase A`, git stops at *every single* commit of B (about 200) asking me to resolve conflicts. Then I run `git mergetool` and I get:

```
Submodule merge conflict for 'isolate':
  {local}: submodule commit 0b28bb5dc58c86f38729a6f06c235bc564033556
  {remote}: deleted
Use (l)ocal or (r)emote, or (a)bort?
```

I tried to enable git rerere by running `git config --global rerere.enabled 1` and I did call `git rerere` after having "resolved" (by just typing <kbd>L</kbd>).

The problem is: by looking in the `.git/rr-cache/` folder I can see that it has recorded one resolution, but it is about the only time (in over 20 resolutions) where I did have to really resolve a conflict.

Maybe rerere doesn't record this type of resolution? If that's the case, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought it would have been too tedious to do:

```
git mergetool
# type "l", type "enter"
git rebase --continue
```

but then I did this:

```
echo "l" | git mergetool && git rebase --continue
```

and it was a lot faster, so I just did it for all commits.

However, if anyone finds it, I'm still interested in a better solution :)